# Resource id#1 Error in PHP

Tags: php

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>New Document</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <?
 $file = fopen("drug.txt", "r") or die("Can't open file");
 echo $file;
 ?>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

I am new to php and trying to open this file I get "Resource Id #1" as an error

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error. `$file` *is* a resource. You have to use `fread` to actually get some data out of that file, or use `file_get_contents` to read the whole file as a string instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Mark's remark, here is the code that will work:

```
<?php
$file = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
?>
```